# how can I resolve dependancy issues after installing with --legacy-peer-deps flag?

Tags: node.js, npm

Recently installed npm package called `react-infinite-scroll-component` with the flag of `--legacy-peer-deps` after installing the package, I can't run `npm run dev` `npm run build` it gives so many errors. I know these errors weren't there before install the above packages. How can I go back to last dependency three?

Already uninstalled the package. `npm uninstall react-infinite-scroll-component` and also tried `npm remove react-infinite-scroll-component`

existing version of Node `v20.7.0` NPM version `10.1.0`

erros :

> warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected:
>
> - The root value has an unexpected property, 0, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath,
>   cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir,
>   env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap,
>   future, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions,
>   i18n, images, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output,
>   outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader,
>   productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode,
>   redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig,
>   staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, typescript,
>   useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).
> - The root value has an unexpected property, 1, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath,
>   cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir,
>   env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap,
>
> > [PWA] Build in develop mode, cache and precache are mostly disabled. This means offline support is disabled, but you can continue
> > developing other functions in service worker.
>
> [PWA] Compile server
> [PWA] Compile server
> error - ./src/layout/Footer.tsx:3:0
> Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material/Box'
> 1 | import React, { useState } from 'react';
> 2 | import { Typography, useMediaQuery } from "@material-ui/core"
> 3 | import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
> 4 | import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap"
> 5 | import styles from './layout.module.scss';
> 6 | import Link from 'next/link'

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

Step 1: get the commit id by using `git log`

```
git reset --hard <commitId> && git clean -f
```

Step 2:  
Deleted `node_modules` and `.next` folders

Step 3:

```
npm ci --legacy-peer-deps
```